# Unity C# Imported PNG won't show up in sprite source image

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, sprite

In my unity C# project I want to assign an important PNG image to a sprite. However the images I have important don't show up in the sprite selection menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably just need to select the right import setting. Namely `Sprite` instead of `Default`.

[image: Import settings]

Comment: Thanks I feel like an idiot now, I haven't used unity for years, thanks for your help.

Comment: @CallumWilliams They change stuff *all the time,* its crazy. Glad to help. Don't forget to up and mark as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

in your Project tab find your imported PNG and select it. Inspector will display the import settings for your PNG. Change `Texture Type` (the very first dropdown in inspector) from `Default` to `Sprite 2D and UI`. Now the image will behave like a sprite.